# How to disable the display of pagebreaks for the workbook in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to disable the display of page breaks for the single worksheet in Excel,but i want to disable for the whole workbook at a time .Please someone help me to disable the display of pagebreaks for the workbook by using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, but here's what you need:

```
Sub DisablePagebreak()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Next
End Sub
```

`Worksheets` is the collection of all `Worksheets` from the current `Workbook`. As the name's implying `.DisplayPageBreaks` hides/shows the page breaks.